# Python app deployed to Heroku : No matching distribution found

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I built a app using dash framework and am attempting to deploy the app to heroku. My `requirements.txt` looks something like this:

```
   pandas
   dash
   Flask
   sklearn
   ... 
   ...
   ...
   sympy
   statsmodel
```

I get an error when installing `sympy` and/or `statsmodel`

```
Collecting sympy
remote:          Downloading sympy-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.9 MB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement statsmodel (from -r /tmp/build_800c2283/requirements.txt (line 18)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for statsmodel (from -r /tmp/build_800c2283/requirements.txt (line 18))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
```

Based on the documentation, packages with unsupported dependencies that do not provide many wheels will not install. Is there a workaround to this?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip

Comment: Try removing statsmodel from requirements.txt

Comment: Don't create your `requirements.txt` manually. Use the command `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`. That will write the file automatically with you with the library versions you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is package name `statsmodel`.

```sh
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement statsmodel
```

The package is called `statsmodels`. You forgot to end with `s`.  See installations [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/install.html)